# how to return names of columns that share a value?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to return the names of columns that share a value. I'm thinking I can make a query to the database, and extract the names.

For example, I want to return `Director` and `Actors` columns when my shared value is `Tarantino` since he is both an actor and a director.

```
String x = "Tarantino";

String q =
        "SELECT Actors, Director, Genre, Country, Released, WHERE Actors LIKE '%"+x+"%' " +
        "AND WHERE Director LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
        "AND WHERE Genre LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
        "AND WHERE Country LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
        "AND WHERE Released LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " ;
```

And then I can iterate over the cursor and get the column names `Director` and `Actors`

Comment: I think your syntax is wrong but it's hard to tell without a better description of your table(s) and columns. Can you provide the DDL or brief description?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the query. I think I'm wrong to assume an empty column won't be returned in the query. For example, the genre column will be empty because Tarantino is not genre. I was hoping to retrieive only the non empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

To look for a match in one column, try this:

```
select exists (select * from actors where director like '%"+x+"%');
```

To put all four together, you can try:

```
select q1, q2, q3, q4 
from
  (select exists (...) as q1)
  join
  (select exists (...) as q2)
  join
  (select exists (...) as q3)
  join
  (select exists (...) as q4)
```

SUPERSEDED:

Have you tried:

```
    "SELECT Actors, Director, Genre, Country, Released, WHERE Actors LIKE '%"+x+"%' " +
    "AND Director LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
    "AND Genre LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
    "AND Country LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " +
    "AND Released LIKE  '%"+x+"%' " ;
```

Note that the way SELECT works, it returns all columns. You query should return a *row* that matches all four of your criteria. However, I think you are trying to do something different. Exactly what is not clear to me.

Comment: I'm trying to return only the columns that contain the value Tarantino. I just need their names.

Comment: Ok, so you want to know which columns contain a value with x embedded. Further, you don't care which row those matches occur in. So, I think what you need is essentially four queries, one for each column. I'm not an SQL expert but I'll try modifying my answer, above.